# How to create list or dictionary, from .txt raw file (logs from controller)

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I have some problem with solve of this problem. I have .txt file, in this file another program write logs from biometric controller, log have format: **"client_id,pin,code,door_num,time_insec"** like a **"12,1,200,2,15000"**, then i format this logs to human-readable format. Like a:

> **['John Smith', '8:33', '01.01.1995']**

I create on Python (3.9.6) script, who transfer all rows from **.txt** to list:

```
myList = [
['John Smith', '8:33', '01.01.1995'],
['John Smith', '14:12', '01.01.1995'],
['Ben Smith', '6:13', '01.01.1995'],
['Ben Smith', '14:43', '01.01.1995'],
['Ben Smith', '4:13', '02.01.1995'],
['Ben Smith', '12:33', '02.01.1995'],
]
```

Then i need create dictionary, with subdictionary, this code need take keys from first list. And this dictionary need to be in this format **{name: {date: [first_time, second_time]}}**:

```
myDictionary = {
'John Smith': {'01.01.1995': ['8:33', '14:12']},
'Ben Smith': {'01.01.1995': ['6:13', '14:43'], '02.01.1995': ['4:13', '12:33']},
}
```

This formated dictionary in next step used to auto-create html-table. So, i need maybe dictionary type, not a list. Pleace, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that your input data structure is consistent for indexing, you COULD do something like this.

```
    myList = [
    ['John Smith', '8:33', '01.01.1995'],
    ['John Smith', '14:12', '01.01.1995'],
    ['Ben Smith', '6:13', '01.01.1995'],
    ['Ben Smith', '14:43', '01.01.1995'],
    ['Ben Smith', '4:13', '02.01.1995'],
    ['Ben Smith', '12:33', '02.01.1995'],
    ]
    
    
    myDictionary = {}
    
    for row in myList:
    
        myDictionary.setdefault(row[0], {})
        myDictionary[row[0]].setdefault(row[2], []).append(row[1])
    
    
    print(myDictionary)
```

Output -

```
{'Ben Smith': {'01.01.1995': ['6:13', '14:43'],
               '02.01.1995': ['4:13', '12:33']},
 'John Smith': {'01.01.1995': ['8:33', '14:12']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something you might want to consider is using a .csv file and opening it with Pandas to add columns and labels. Something like this would work:

.csv file:

```
client_id,pin,code,door_num,time_insec
12,1,200,2,15000
```

code to read the file:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('list from csv.csv', sep=',')
data = data[["client_id","pin","code","door_num","time_insec"]]
print(data)
```